# Cypress passes test on uncaught exception during retry attempt 2

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception

It's a weird bug that I am experiencing.

My test fails due to a detached element from DOM(this is not the issue) and it auto-triggers a retry since I have retries enabled and set the number of attempts to 2.
However, as soon as cypress begins executing the second attempt, I am getting the following uncaught exception.

[image]

The point is, cypress passes the test where the uncaught exception occurred during the second attempt.
It's causing me to believe that the tests have passed, whereas, in reality, no cypress commands were executed during the second attempt.
I am unable to reproduce this in any other code, and unfortunately, cannot share the scripts due to company policy.
Any tips, resolution, debug guidance here would be helpful.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. What is the best way to workaround this one?
The retry passes only when there is an uncaught exception in the first run.